# Cannot fix global packages vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, security, npm

- When I run `npm update -g`, I get this enormous list of vulnerabilities on the screenshot [image: below.]
- I tried to globally update `npm` to the latest version, and I tried to install `npm-check-updates`. I updated something with it, and now `ncu -g` gives me 'All global packages are up to date'.
  `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` don't do anything.
  Yet, all the vulnerabilities are still here. What can I do about it?
  Here's list of globally installed packages I have:
  [image]
- And here's the output of `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` while I'm in the directory where the global packages are installed:
  [image]

If I delete `package-lock.json`, `npm audit fix` doesn't run at all and wants me to initialize npm in this global packages directory with package-json.only. After doing so, it gives me the output from above.

**How can I fix these vulnerabilites? Or do I need to care about them at all?**